# Delphi TRegEx Replace

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to replace character in a big string all character @ by #13#10 if they match the pattern.

But how to get my the value of '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' of my pattern to put in my replacement field ?

```
pattern := '@' + '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' + '\$';
replacement := #13#10 + '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' + '\$';
ts.Text := TRegEx.Replace(AString, pattern, replacement, [roIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: What is your pattern? `@` then 7 digits then a literal `$`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To perform your check you can use a positive lookahead:

```
pattern := '@(?=[0-9]{7}\$)'
replacement := #13#10
```

The `(?=...)` will check the `@` is followed by what you want, without selecting these following digits.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
TRegEx.Replace(s, '@([0-9]{7}\$)', #13#10+'\1')
```

To break it down:

- `[0-9]{7}` means 7 occurrences of a digit.
- The parens `(...)` are used to capture the 7 digits and the `$`.
- The `\1` in the replacement string expands to the captured string.

Although Robin's approach is nicer!

Comment: I would rather you accepted Robin's answer. It is better. Thanks all the same mind you!